# Spring MVC beans included by default

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, netbeans

I'm newbie in SpringMVC and when I create new web-application project in `NetBeans 8.0` I see that `dispatcher-servlet.xml` contains the following:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

Could you explain in a nutshell what purpose of these beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Client requests for a Resource in the web application, the Spring Front Controller intercepts the request and tries to find the appropriate handler mapping.

The Handler mapping maps the request from the client to its controller object by browsing over various controllers defined in the configuration file.

```
    <bean id="urlMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

This is a Handler Mapping Bean. The core purpose of this bean is to map the request to the controller object.

SimpleUrlHandlerMapping is the simplest Handler Mapping that directly maps the Client Request to the Controller object.

Inside the Property tag, we have a 'prop' element with the 'Key' attribute being the Url and value being the identifier of the Controller object.

Now that we know which controller object to forward the request to, the Handler Adapter forwards the request to the controller object.

```
         <bean name="indexController"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
  p:viewName="index" />
```

This is a Controller Bean that implements the Controller interface

The HandleRequest method in the controller returns the ModelAndView object with the logical view name. The view resolver maps the logical view name and the physical location of the view

```
  <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
  p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

This is the View Resolver Bean, which maps the Logical name and the Physical View Location.

InternalResourceViewResolver is one of the built-in Spring Resolvers.

Comment: One clarification: Spring Front Controller = DispatcherServlet?

Comment: Yes, that's right!. DispatcherServlet is an expression of the "FrontController" design pattern